# Remove the bottom border of TextField

Tags: css, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I would like to remove the bottom border of TextField of Fluent UI. I tried the following code, but it did not work.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { TextField } from "@fluentui/react";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <TextField
      style={{
        textarea: { border: "none", borderBottom: "none" },
        input: { border: "none", borderBottom: "none" }
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Could anyone help?

PS: CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-ramanujan-0jcsw1?file=/src/App.js:0-280

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The border is defined on the `fieldGroup` element of the TextField. So this should work using the `ITextFieldStyles` interface:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { TextField } from "@fluentui/react";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <TextField
      styles={{
        fieldGroup: { borderBottom: "none" }
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Adjusted sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-chandrasekhar-rp3x8f?file=/src/App.js:0-210

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code on your .css

```
.no-border {
  border-bottom: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

and this on your code

```
import "./styles.css";
import { TextField } from "@fluentui/react";

export default function App() {
  return <TextField className="no-border" />;
}
```

Comment: It does not seem to work.